# Presentation of $hS$ as in page 29 of HTT

Tags: combinatorics, category-theory, higher-category-theory

At the page claims 29 of HTT, Lurie claims that the category $hS$ (we ignore all the enrichement) admits the following presentation by generators and relation :

- The objects of $hS$ are the vertices of $S$ (this one is clear).
- For every edge $ f: \Delta^1 \rightarrow S$ there is  a morphism $\overline{f}$ in $hS$.
- For each $2$-simplex $\sigma$ we have $\overline{d_0\sigma} \circ \overline{d_2\sigma} = \overline{d_1\sigma}$.
- For each vertex $x$ the morphism $\overline{s_0x}$ is the identity $id_x$.

He claims that this follows from the fact the functor $h$ is left adjoint to the nerve functor but I don't see how.

We first idea was to use Yoneda and try to use the adjunction on $sSet( \Delta^1, S)$ to get the statement about morphisms but the adjunction isnot in the correct direction. 
Then I tought about using that $h\Delta^1 \cong [1]$ as a category and use that that the set of morphisms in $hS$ is in bijection with $Cat([1], hS)$ but I did not get much result.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your $\LaTeX$. Anyway, the point is that $h$ is cocontinuous. So this is immediately true for the 2-skeleton of $S$ via its decomposition as a colimit of simplices. And the higher-dimensional simplices don't affect anything here. More formally, you can check that $h$ sends the $n$-sphere and the $n+1$-simplex to the same category for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: It's funny because nothing was wrong, it came out perfectly under the box where I  wrote my code.  I just resubmitted it and now it's fine.